# How do I get a value from a service in angular and insert it into an exported class?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a large object that is hard coded into my application, I am trying to use a service to get the same object from a place in the web so that it always stays up to date without me having to go in and edit the code on a daily basis.I tried to build a service and inject it into the class but I moved the service code into the constructor of the class because when you create a new instance it expects a parameter, I know how to inject the service into a component.ts however I don't know how to inject it into a regular class, which I will be using my assigning it to a variable using the new keyword like so:

```
var a = new OBJ();
```

here is the code for the service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DateAPIService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getApi() {
    return this.http.get(
      "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzs4iOgmrDAOjgrwOeBybtiT0Pkx3ry06pXzgvGmzTIxgm94DBC/exec"
    );
  }
}
```

here is the code for the class after I moved the code from the service to the constructor of the class (This is what I'm trying to figure out):

```
export class datesTable {
    dates = {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http
      .get(
        "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzs4iOgmrDAOjgrwOeBybtiT0Pkx3ry06pXzgvGmzTIxgm94DBC/exec"
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        //@ts-ignore
        this.dates = data.dates;
      });
  }
}
```

Example implementation of datesTable class:

```
Developers = {
  Bluegreen: {
    dates: new datesTable().dates
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datesTable constructor() should be like this :

```
constructor(private myService: DateAPIService ) {}
myFunction(){
  this.myService.getApi().subscribe((data)=>{
     console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Then you can call myFunction() from all the objects you create.

```
Developers = {
Bluegreen: {
  dates: new datesTable().myFunction()
 }
}
```